# Asymptotic analysis of $T(n) = T(n/5) + T(4n/5) + \Theta(n)$

Tags: asymptotics, discrete-mathematics

If I have a recurrence relationship like this:
$$T(n) = T(n/5) + T(4n/5) + \Theta(n),$$
how would I analyze its rate of growth?

I believe I can't use the master theorem. I tried to draw a tree but some of the branches terminate earlier. There's a way to calculate the big-O notation by assuming $T(n) \le 2 T(4n/5)$, but does this result in a tight estimate?

Comment: @greybeard Sorry I didn't make it clear enough. I'm saying that I could calculate the upper bound for T(n) = T(n/5) + T(4n/5) + Θ(n) by reducing it to T(n) <= 2T(4n/5) + Θ(n). But I also want to get its lower bound, the big theta notation. Does what I do here give me that result?

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with running time.

Answer (score 3):

Your recurrence can be solved using the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), a vast generalization of the master theorem. The result is $\Theta(n\log n)$.

You can also see this using a recursion tree. The root is labeled $n$. An internal vertex $m$ has children labeled $m/5$ and $4m/5$. Vertices are leaves if their labels is at most some arbitrary positive constant $C$, say $C=1$. The running time is proportional to the sum of all labels.

We can partition the vertices in the tree to levels according to their distance from the root. The first $\log_5 n$ levels of so are "complete", that is, their labels sum to $n$, and there are $\log_{5/4} n$ levels in total, so the sum of labels is between $n\log_5 n$ and $n\log_{5/4} n$ levels. In particular, the complexity is $\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is my first question on stack overflow so thank you for fixing the format for me. Appreciate again!
Only one more thing, is what you wrote here sufficient enough for a formal proof? (I'm talking about the second and the third paragraph). If not, what other details do I need to add?